# Developer story: Missing work experience

Tags: discussion, bug, design, developer-story

I have finally decided to start putting down my Developer Story. I added personal information and then filled out Work Experience and Education, in that order.

So far, so good. However, after pressing `Save` on the Education tab, it closed itself, automatically I believe. Since this is my first time using it, I needed some time to notice that in the story view there is no Position. All my details in the other tab - Work Experience, were nowhere to be found. I looked around, but I could find nothing of what I wrote initially. Now, unless somewhere hidden, I have to write the whole form over again...

Even, if I closed the initial window by myself (after saving the Education form), it should have warned me that I have unsaved information. Therefore I consider two possible reasons:

- It silently threw away the information and didn't update the story.
- There could be some initial restrictions in play, e.g. for students (as me), who haven't completed their education yet. This is highly unlikely, since one could add a Position later manually.

In any case, it is either a bug or bad design.

Should I file a bug report here or a moderator would investigate the issue further beforehand?

**EDIT:** As of now I assume I have to file a report.